# Multiply a column based on a category of another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to transform a value of one column based on a categorical value of another column. So if the size of a column catchable I need to multiply the Fingerling by 11.08 and similar for the other sizes.

| Year | Water | Species | Size | LbsStocked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | Beaver | RBT | Catch | 1845 |
| 2018 | Beaver | RBT | Yrl | 100 |
| 2019 | Beaver | RBT | Fingerling | 200 |

```
library(ggplot2)
require(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

####BEAVER FISH STOCKED
BData<-read_excel("Stocking Numbers_ALL_2006-2020.xlsx",
                 sheet = "AllSystemsLBs")
BData <- aggregate(LbsStocked ~ Year + Water + Species + Size, data=BData, FUN=sum)
BData <- filter(BData, Water == "Beaver Tailwater")
BData <- BData %>%
 mutate(LbsStocked = case_when(Size == "Fingerling" ~ LbsStocked * 11.08,
                        Size == "Catchable"  ~ LbsStocked * 1.84,
                        Size == "Yrl" ~ LbsStocked * 3.55,
                        TRUE ~ LbsStocked))
```

The mutate (case_when) command I am using currently is only adding significant figures and not multiplying the LbsStocked.

Comment: I added some sample data, I'm pretty sure small things like capitalization and misspelling aren't the culprit.

Comment: With your example, it is working fine though i.e. `BData %>%
 mutate(LbsStocked = case_when(Size == "Fingerling" ~ LbsStocked * 11.08,
                        Size == "Catchable"  ~ LbsStocked * 1.84,
                        Size == "Yrl" ~ LbsStocked * 3.55,
                        TRUE ~ as.numeric(LbsStocked))) %>% pull(LbsStocked)#[1] 1845  355 2216`

Comment: i.e. `> 100 *3.55
[1] 355
> 200 * 11.08
[1] 2216`

Comment: If you are not getting the same output with the code, it is better to post the `dput(BData)` which gives the correct structure for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
    BData <- BData  %>%
      select(Year, Water, Species, Size, LbsStocked) %>%
         mutate(LbsStocked_adj = case_when(Size == "Fingerling" ~               LbsStocked * 11.08,
                                           Size == "Catchable"  ~ LbsStocked * 1.84,
                                           Size == "Yrl" ~ LbsStocked * 3.55))
```

LbsStocked_adj will be a separate variable with this.